# React + Marked.js in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm following the [comments React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) using Rails with the [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails). Consider the `Comment` component:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <span className="commentAuthor">
          <strong>{this.props.author}</strong>
        </span>
        <br/>
        {marked(this.props.children.toString())}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Which is used like this:

```
<Comment author="Jordan Walke">This is *another* comment</Comment>
```

the markdown is correctly transformed, but the elements are displayed like if they were non-html-safe:

```
<p>This is <em>another</em> comment</p>
```

The component is rendered in Rails with

```
<%= react_component('CommentList', {prerender: true}) %>
```

and I've also tried:

```
<%= react_component('CommentList') %>
<%= react_component('CommentList', {prerender: true}).html_safe %>
```

And here's the code for the `CommentList`:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        <Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
        <Comment author="Jordan Walke">This is *another* comment</Comment>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

So my question is: how can I render the markdown-converted comment in an HTML-safe way?

**EDIT**

Sorry, the answer was right there in the tutorial:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <span className="commentAuthor">
          <strong>{this.props.author}</strong>
        </span>
        <br/>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```